# How to truncate a text in a custom GtkCellRenderer?

Tags: gtk, cellrenderer, gtktreeview

I trying to create custom GtkCellRenderer with some text. And I want this text truncated, when a size of GtkCellRenderer is smaller than size of text. For example:

[alt text](http://rghost.ru/1797658/image.png)

How can I do this? Is this some property of CellRenderer or PangoLayout or I need to do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ellipsize` and `ellipsize-set` properties of `GtkCellRendererText`.

If you want to do it manually with Pango, use `pango_layout_set_ellipsize()`.

Comment: But I'm extending GtkCellRenderer, not GtkCellRendererText.

Comment: Why not subclass `GtkCellRendererText`? Do you want to make something like in the picture you posted? Then you would be better off using two columns, one with `GtkCellRendererPixbuf` and one `GtkCellRendererText`. But also see edit above.

Comment: Thank you, pango_layout_set_ellipsize - probably is what I need. But when I use it, instead of the text displayed only three dots. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: You need to use it in combination with `pango_layout_set_width()`.

Comment: Can you give an example of overloading a `Gtk.CellRendererText` please?